# allure.createAttachment exception error - Cannot read property 'currentStep' of undefined

Tags: protractor, mocha.js, allure

I can successfully add screenshots to allure reports, but i get the following exception error:

error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentStep' of undefined
    at Allure.addAttachment (/Users//xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/allure-js-commons/index.js:86:45)
    at Allure.createAttachment (/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/allure-js-commons/runtime.js:48:29)
    at /Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/lib/class/class-name.js:30:20
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

class:

```
 browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
            allure.createAttachment(title, new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
        }).catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Are you getting error or only exception?. And were do you use `currentStep` in your project?

Comment: just exception. I seemed to have solved it by adding a try, catch. Is this the right approach? `try {
            await browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
                allure.createAttachment(title, new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error caught');
        }`

Comment: and im not using `currentStep`, is it coming from `createAttachment`?

Comment: @user I'm guessing your script is still printing out `Error caught` from the code in the comment you posted? Your try/catch will simply hide the exception as you are not printing it any longer. You could structure your .then/.catch the same way if you want. It is better to try and find why that exception is occurring. Do you use any other `takeScreenshot` or `allure.createAttachment` anywhere else in your code successfully?

Comment: this is the place I am using `takeScreenshot` and `allure.createAttachment`

Comment: @user11185751  Try with callback pattern like below code:
var dumpLog = allure.createAttachment("my log [{0}]", function(level, log) {
        return new Buffer(log, "utf-8");
    });
    var firstStep = allure.createStep("simple step", function() {});

Answer (score 1):

```
const allure = require('mocha-allure-reporter');
```

allure is a global identifier, injected by reporter to your code.

Add the following line to the top of your file to tell Typescript about it

```
declare const allure: any;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think createAttachment requires a callback function and not a buffer being passed directly.

Can you try changing your code to reflect the following

```
browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
    allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function () {
        return new Buffer(png, 'base64')
    }, 'image/png')()
}).catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
```